# Error in dynamic SQL while importing data from a temporary into a permanent table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

This is my query:

```
Declare @i int
Declare @Query nvarchar(max)

Set @i = 1

while(@i < 3)
begin
    Select YEAR, MONTH 
    into #temp 
    from Toyota1

    Set @Query = 'Select * into table'+ CASt(@i AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'from #temp'

    Set @i = @i + 1 

    exec (@query)

    Drop Table #temp
end
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '#temp'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '#temp'.

Please help.

Comment: maybe you need a space in front of your FROM :P

Comment: You missed a space before `from #temp`. It should be `Set @Query = 'Select * into table'+ CASt(@i AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' from #temp'`

Comment: ^^ top two comments have the answer. If you have a dsql query which doesn't execute, the first step would normally be to print it out to look at it yourself, so that you can examine why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
DECLARE @i     INT = 1
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;
SELECT TOP (0) [YEAR], [MONTH]
INTO #temp 
FROM Toyota1;


WHILE(@i < 3)
BEGIN
  INSERT #temp ([YEAR], [MONTH])
  SELECT [YEAR], [MONTH]
  FROM Toyota1
  WHERE <some logic here that requires a loop>

  SET @i += 1
END

SELECT * 
INTO <TABLE> 
FROM #temp;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```